# Issue with addPath in zend framework

Tags: php, zend-framework, frameworks

I'm currently reading the "Easy PHP Websites with the Zend Framework". At some point, it introduces Doctrine and gives a src code along with an text on how to install stuff properly.
I've followed all the steps correctly, but in one you have to use a "seed.php" which reads some ASINs and loads some amazon product details into the databass.
However, executing the script gives me errors, and it seems like it can't locate a file.

> > > PHP Warning:  include_once(WJG\Controller\Action\Helper\Initializer.php): failed  to
> > >       open stream: No such file or directory in
> > >       C:\Programming\zend\library\Zend\L oader.php on line 134 PHP Stack
> > >       trace:  PHP
> > >       1. {main}() C:\wamp\www\webclass\application\scripts\seed.php:0 PHP
> > >       2. include() C:\wamp\www\webclass\application\scripts\seed.php:9 PHP
> > >       3.  Zend_Application->bootstrap() C:\wamp\www\webclass\public\cli.php:20
> > >       4. Zend_Application_Bootstrap_BootstrapAbstract->bootstrap() C:\Programmin g\zend\library\Zend\Application.php:355 PHP
> > >       5. Zend_Application_Bootstrap_BootstrapAbstract->_bootstrap()
> > >       C:\Programmi
> > >       ng\zend\library\Zend\Application\Bootstrap\BootstrapAbstract.php:586
> > >       PHP
> > >       6.Zend_Application_Bootstrap_BootstrapAbstract->_executeResource()
> > >       C:\Pro
> > >       gramming\zend\library\Zend\Application\Bootstrap\BootstrapAbstract.php:622
> > >       PHP
> > >       7. Bootstrap->_initGlobalVars() C:\Programming\zend\library\Zend\Applicati
> > >       on\Bootstrap\BootstrapAbstract.php:669 PHP
> > >       8.Zend_Loader_Autoloader::autoload()
> > >       C:\Programming\zend\library\Zend\App
> > >       lication\Bootstrap\BootstrapAbstract.php:0 PHP
> > >       9. call_user_func() C:\Programming\zend\library\Zend\Loader\Autoloader.php :124 PHP
> > >       10.Zend_Loader_Autoloader->_autoload()
> > >       C:\Programming\zend\library\Zend\Lo ader\Autoloader.php:124 PHP
> > >       11. call_user_func()
> > >       C:\Programming\zend\library\Zend\Loader\Autoloader.php :479 PHP
> > >       12. Zend_Loader::loadClass()
> > >       C:\Programming\zend\library\Zend\Loader\Autolo ader.php:479 PHP
> > >       13. Zend_Loader::loadFile() C:\Programming\zend\library\Zend\Loader.php:82
>
> Warning: include_once(WJG\Controller\Action\Helper\Initializer.php):
>   failed to o pen stream: No such file or directory in
>   C:\Programming\zend\library\Zend\Loader .php on line 134
>
> Call Stack:
>       0.0004     651544   1. {main}() C:\wamp\www\webclass\application\scripts\see d.php:0
>       0.0006     661568   2. include('C:\wamp\www\webclass\public\cli.php') C:\wam
>   p\www\webclass\application\scripts\seed.php:9
>       0.0121    2052384   3. Zend_Application->bootstrap() C:\wamp\www\webclass\pu blic\cli.php:20
>       0.0121    2052432   4. Zend_Application_Bootstrap_BootstrapAbstract->bootstr ap()
>   C:\Programming\zend\library\Zend\Application.php:355
>       0.0121    2052432   5. Zend_Application_Bootstrap_BootstrapAbstract->_bootst rap()
>   C:\Programming\zend\library\Zend\Application\Bootstrap\BootstrapAbstract.p
>   hp:586
>       0.0190    3235544   6. Zend_Application_Bootstrap_BootstrapAbstract->_execut eResource()
>   C:\Programming\zend\library\Zend\Application\Bootstrap\BootstrapAbst
>   ract.php:622
>       0.0190    3235768   7. Bootstrap->_initGlobalVars() C:\Programming\zend\libr
>   ary\Zend\Application\Bootstrap\BootstrapAbstract.php:669
>       0.0190    3236432   8. Zend_Loader_Autoloader::autoload() C:\Programming\zen
>   d\library\Zend\Application\Bootstrap\BootstrapAbstract.php:0
>       0.0191    3236768   9. call_user_func() C:\Programming\zend\library\Zend\Loa der\Autoloader.php:124
>       0.0191    3236800  10. Zend_Loader_Autoloader->_autoload() C:\Programming\ze nd\library\Zend\Loader\Autoloader.php:124
>       0.0191    3236848  11. call_user_func() C:\Programming\zend\library\Zend\Loa der\Autoloader.php:479
>       0.0191    3236880  12. Zend_Loader::loadClass() C:\Programming\zend\library\ Zend\Loader\Autoloader.php:479
>       0.0191    3237136  13. Zend_Loader::loadFile() C:\Programming\zend\library\Z end\Loader.php:82
>
> PHP Warning:  include_once(): Failed opening
>   'WJG\Controller\Action\Helper\Initi alizer.php' for inclusion
>   (include_path='C:\wamp\www\webclass\application/../vie
>   ws;.;C:\wamp\bin\php\php5.3.13\pear;c:\php\includes;C:\Programming\zend\library;
>   C:\wamp\bin\php\php5.3.13\pear\PEAR') in
>   C:\Programming\zend\library\Zend\Loader .php on line 134 PHP Stack
>   trace: PHP   1. {main}()
>   C:\wamp\www\webclass\application\scripts\seed.php:0 PHP   2. include()
>   C:\wamp\www\webclass\application\scripts\seed.php:9 PHP   3.
>   Zend_Application->bootstrap() C:\wamp\www\webclass\public\cli.php:20
>   PHP   4. Zend_Application_Bootstrap_BootstrapAbstract->bootstrap()
>   C:\Programmin g\zend\library\Zend\Application.php:355 PHP   5.
>   Zend_Application_Bootstrap_BootstrapAbstract->_bootstrap()
>   C:\Programmi
>   ng\zend\library\Zend\Application\Bootstrap\BootstrapAbstract.php:586
>   PHP   6.
>   Zend_Application_Bootstrap_BootstrapAbstract->_executeResource()
>   C:\Pro
>   gramming\zend\library\Zend\Application\Bootstrap\BootstrapAbstract.php:622
>   PHP   7. Bootstrap->_initGlobalVars()
>   C:\Programming\zend\library\Zend\Applicati
>   on\Bootstrap\BootstrapAbstract.php:669 PHP   8.
>   Zend_Loader_Autoloader::autoload()
>   C:\Programming\zend\library\Zend\App
>   lication\Bootstrap\BootstrapAbstract.php:0 PHP   9. call_user_func()
>   C:\Programming\zend\library\Zend\Loader\Autoloader.php :124 PHP  10.
>   Zend_Loader_Autoloader->_autoload()
>   C:\Programming\zend\library\Zend\Lo ader\Autoloader.php:124 PHP  11.
>   call_user_func()
>   C:\Programming\zend\library\Zend\Loader\Autoloader.php :479 PHP  12.
>   Zend_Loader::loadClass()
>   C:\Programming\zend\library\Zend\Loader\Autolo ader.php:479 PHP  13.
>   Zend_Loader::loadFile() C:\Programming\zend\library\Zend\Loader.php:82
>
> Warning: include_once(): Failed opening
>   'WJG\Controller\Action\Helper\Initialize r.php' for inclusion
>   (include_path='C:\wamp\www\webclass\application/../views;.;
>   C:\wamp\bin\php\php5.3.13\pear;c:\php\includes;C:\Programming\zend\library;C:\wa
>   mp\bin\php\php5.3.13\pear\PEAR') in
>   C:\Programming\zend\library\Zend\Loader.php on line 134
>
> Call Stack:
>       0.0004     651544   1. {main}() C:\wamp\www\webclass\application\scripts\see d.php:0
>       0.0006     661568   2. include('C:\wamp\www\webclass\public\cli.php') C:\wam
>   p\www\webclass\application\scripts\seed.php:9
>       0.0121    2052384   3. Zend_Application->bootstrap() C:\wamp\www\webclass\pu blic\cli.php:20
>       0.0121    2052432   4. Zend_Application_Bootstrap_BootstrapAbstract->bootstr ap()
>   C:\Programming\zend\library\Zend\Application.php:355
>       0.0121    2052432   5. Zend_Application_Bootstrap_BootstrapAbstract->_bootst rap()
>   C:\Programming\zend\library\Zend\Application\Bootstrap\BootstrapAbstract.p
>   hp:586
>       0.0190    3235544   6. Zend_Application_Bootstrap_BootstrapAbstract->_execut eResource()
>   C:\Programming\zend\library\Zend\Application\Bootstrap\BootstrapAbst
>   ract.php:622
>       0.0190    3235768   7. Bootstrap->_initGlobalVars() C:\Programming\zend\libr
>   ary\Zend\Application\Bootstrap\BootstrapAbstract.php:669
>       0.0190    3236432   8. Zend_Loader_Autoloader::autoload() C:\Programming\zen
>   d\library\Zend\Application\Bootstrap\BootstrapAbstract.php:0
>       0.0191    3236768   9. call_user_func() C:\Programming\zend\library\Zend\Loa der\Autoloader.php:124
>       0.0191    3236800  10. Zend_Loader_Autoloader->_autoload() C:\Programming\ze nd\library\Zend\Loader\Autoloader.php:124
>       0.0191    3236848  11. call_user_func() C:\Programming\zend\library\Zend\Loa der\Autoloader.php:479
>       0.0191    3236880  12. Zend_Loader::loadClass() C:\Programming\zend\library\ Zend\Loader\Autoloader.php:479
>       0.0191    3237136  13. Zend_Loader::loadFile() C:\Programming\zend\library\Z end\Loader.php:82
>
> PHP Fatal error:  Class 'WJG_Controller_Action_Helper_Initializer' not
>   found in C:\wamp\www\webclass\application\Bootstrap.php on line 39 PHP
>   Stack trace: PHP   1. {main}()
>   C:\wamp\www\webclass\application\scripts\seed.php:0 PHP   2. include()
>   C:\wamp\www\webclass\application\scripts\seed.php:9 PHP   3.
>   Zend_Application->bootstrap() C:\wamp\www\webclass\public\cli.php:20
>   PHP   4. Zend_Application_Bootstrap_BootstrapAbstract->bootstrap()
>   C:\Programmin g\zend\library\Zend\Application.php:355 PHP   5.
>   Zend_Application_Bootstrap_BootstrapAbstract->_bootstrap()
>   C:\Programmi
>   ng\zend\library\Zend\Application\Bootstrap\BootstrapAbstract.php:586
>   PHP   6.
>   Zend_Application_Bootstrap_BootstrapAbstract->_executeResource()
>   C:\Pro
>   gramming\zend\library\Zend\Application\Bootstrap\BootstrapAbstract.php:622
>   PHP   7. Bootstrap->_initGlobalVars()
>   C:\Programming\zend\library\Zend\Applicati
>   on\Bootstrap\BootstrapAbstract.php:669
>
> Fatal error: Class 'WJG_Controller_Action_Helper_Initializer' not
>   found in C:\wa mp\www\webclass\application\Bootstrap.php on line 39
>
> Call Stack:
>       0.0004     651544   1. {main}() C:\wamp\www\webclass\application\scripts\see d.php:0
>       0.0006     661568   2. include('C:\wamp\www\webclass\public\cli.php') C:\wam
>   p\www\webclass\application\scripts\seed.php:9
>       0.0121    2052384   3. Zend_Application->bootstrap() C:\wamp\www\webclass\pu blic\cli.php:20
>       0.0121    2052432   4. Zend_Application_Bootstrap_BootstrapAbstract->bootstr ap()
>   C:\Programming\zend\library\Zend\Application.php:355
>       0.0121    2052432   5. Zend_Application_Bootstrap_BootstrapAbstract->_bootst rap()
>   C:\Programming\zend\library\Zend\Application\Bootstrap\BootstrapAbstract.p
>   hp:586
>       0.0190    3235544   6. Zend_Application_Bootstrap_BootstrapAbstract->_execut eResource()
>   C:\Programming\zend\library\Zend\Application\Bootstrap\BootstrapAbst
>   ract.php:622
>       0.0190    3235768   7. Bootstrap->_initGlobalVars() C:\Programming\zend\libr
>   ary\Zend\Application\Bootstrap\BootstrapAbstract.php:669

This is the error, and here is the _initGlobalVars()

```
      protected function _initGlobalVars()
  {

    Zend_Controller_Action_HelperBroker::addPath(APPLICATION_PATH.'/../library/WJG/Controller/Action/Helper');

    $initializer = Zend_Controller_Action_HelperBroker::addHelper(
      new WJG_Controller_Action_Helper_Initializer());

  }
```

If you want some more info ask me, please help me because I really want to continue with the flow of the book, thanks!

Comment: the errors seem clear to me, they files are not being included

Comment: Indeed. The error indicates it can't find the file `WJG\Controller\Action\Helper\Initializer.php`. Does this file exist?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add prefix to the path:
`Zend_Controller_Action_HelperBroker::addPath(APPLICATION_PATH.'/../library/WJG/Controller/Action/Helper');`

add then:
`Zend_Controller_Action_HelperBroker::addPrefix("WJG_Controller_Action_Helper_");`

Hope this helps :)